# Adding data with wildcard at the beginning of the path

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this specific pattern in my realtime Database in Firebase.

For example:

the string user as a constant -> user ID as a variable -> notification as a constant string -> message ID as variable -> userName as a constant string

```
'/user/' + 1234567 + '/notification/'+ 121212 + '/userName/'
'/user/' + 3454234 + '/notification/'+ 121212 + '/userName/'
'/user/' + 0893464 + '/notification/'+ 232323 + '/userName/'
```

and I want to add some content but only to a few of these above.

```
var ref = db.ref('/user/' + userID + '/notification/'+ 121212 + '/userName/').set(nameUser);
```

On every path where the message ID is 121212 it should do the action above. How can I do this? With wildcards?
The user ID is unkown/ always different.

The code should look like this:

```
'/user/' + wildcard + '/notification/'+ 121212 + '/userName/' -> posting here
'/user/' + wildcard + '/notification/'+ 121212 + '/userName/' -posting here
'/user/' + wildcard + '/notification/'+ 232323 + '/userName/'
```

Comment: Why not using a simple `(if === '121212')` block??

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? I dont understand how I should implement that.

Comment: It’s difficult to answer because we don’t see how you get the three strings. In a loop? You should share more code that shows the context

Comment: The 3 strings are generated with my iOS App. I just want to post to every path with using wild cards. The number which come after user are not known. So it should open every path and post nameUser to every path. I updated the code above.

Comment: Just use [String methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) to get the part of the string between `notification/` and `/userName` and check if has the desired value (`121212` in your example). I don't understand where exactly is your problem, sorry.